# Replacing values in one column with values in another

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

I have the following sample `df`

```
import pandas as pd
DateChange = [list(['11/04/1911', '03/06/1919']),
          list(['01/27/1918', '03/27/1984']),
          list(['01/26/1912', '01/15/1918', '02/06/1917'])]
DateGrab = [list(['10.31.11', '03-02-1919']), list(['01-23-18', '03-23-1984']),
       list(['1-22-12', '01.11.18', '2.2.17'])]
df= pd.DataFrame({'Text':['Hey 10.31.11  22|1|13 03-02-1919 d',
                              'things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then ',
                                  'stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 so so '],
                          'ID': ['E1','E2', 'E3'],
                  'DateChange' : DateChange,
                  'DateGrab' : DateGrab

                          })
```

Which looks like

```
                DateChange                 DateGrab                 ID   Text
0   [11/04/1911, 03/06/1919]             [10.31.11, 03-02-1919]     E1  Hey 10.31.11 22|1|13 03-02-1919 d
1   [01/27/1918, 03/27/1984]             [01-23-18, 03-23-1984]     E2  things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then    
2   [01/26/1912, 01/15/1918, 02/06/1917] [1-22-12, 01.11.18, 2.2.17]E3  stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 so so
```

My goal is as follows:

1) If `DateGrab` value e.g `10.31.11` is present in `Text` replace this value in `Text` with  `DateChange` value e.g. `11/04/1911`

2) Create new column

Thus, my desired output is as follows

```
    DateChange DateGrab ID  Text   New_Text
0                                  Hey 11/04/1911 22|1|13 03/06/1919 d
1                                  things here 01/27/1918 or 03/27/1984 then    
2                                  stuff 01/26/1912 01/15/1918 or 02/06/1917 so so
```

I have tried the code below but this doesn't work

```
df['New_Text']= df['Text'].replace(df.Text, df.DateChange)
```

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try take advantage of `df.replace` by dictionary

```
d = {i: dict(zip(dt_grab, dt_change))  for i, (dt_change, dt_grab) 
                                       in enumerate(zip(df.DateChange, df.DateGrab))}

df['New_Text'] = df[['Text']].T.replace(d, regex=True).T

In [30]: df[['New_Text']]
Out[30]:
                                           New_Text
0              Hey 11/04/1911  22|1|13 03/06/1919 d
1        things here 01/27/1918 or 03/27/1984 then
2  stuff 01/26/1912 01/15/1918 or 02/06/1917 so so
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) in pandas 0.25.1:

```
s=df['DateChange'].explode()
s.index=df['DateGrab'].explode()
d=s.to_dict()
for key in d:
    df['New_Text']=df['Text'].str.replace(key,d[key])  
print(df)

                                       Text  ID  \
0        Hey 10.31.11  22|1|13 03-02-1919 d  E1   
1  things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then   E2   
2   stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 so so   E3   

                             DateChange                     DateGrab  \
0              [11/04/1911, 03/06/1919]       [10.31.11, 03-02-1919]   
1              [01/27/1918, 03/27/1984]       [01-23-18, 03-23-1984]   
2  [01/26/1912, 01/15/1918, 02/06/1917]  [1-22-12, 01.11.18, 2.2.17]   

                                      New_Text  
0           Hey 10.31.11  22|1|13 03-02-1919 d  
1     things here 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 then   
2  stuff 1-22-12 01.11.18 or 02/06/1917 so so
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but I get an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: This is because you don't have version 0.25.1 of pandas

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately I am not able to change the version of pandas that I am currently using since doing so will disrupt other aspects of my project :-/